# Custom Form Call using CMS page will not show Magento 2 Captcha code

Tags: magento2.3, forms, cms-pages, captcha

When i call form using direct URL
http://192.168.1.35/m234/customemail/index/index OR http://192.168.1.35/m234/customemail/ it will show Captcha code but when i call this same form using CMS page like

```
{{block class="My\Customemail\Block\Customemail" template="My_Customemail::customemail_index_index.phtml"}}
```

it will not show captcha.
I have an issue in My Latest Magento 2 version 2.3.4.

[image]

[image]